# Wrong path of BASE_URL

Tags: php

I am trying to make a simple CMS, I'm getting a Not Found error.
I double checked paths and everyhing but I really don't know where is the issue.

I believe that something must be wrong with BASE_URL.

Error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /traderMVC/page.php was not found on this erver.

Project structure:

[image: click for structure]

index.php

```
    require 'app/config.php';
    
    $pages = $con->query("SELECT id,label,slug FROM posts")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
    require VIEW_ROOT .'/home.php';
```

home.php

```
    <?php require VIEW_ROOT .'/templates/header.php'; ?>
    
    <?php if(empty($pages)): ?>
        <p>Sorry, no pages at the moment!</p>
    
    <?php else: ?>
        <ul>
    
            <?php foreach ($pages as $page): ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>page.php?page=<?php echo $page['slug']; ?>"><?php echo $page['label']; ?></a></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
     
        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
    
    <?php require VIEW_ROOT .'/templates/footer.php'; ?>
```

config.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

define('APP_ROOT', __DIR__);
define('VIEW_ROOT', APP_ROOT . '/../views');
define('BASE_URL', 'http://localhost/traderMVC/');

$con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cms', 'root', 'root');
```

page.php

```
<h1>test ....</h1>
```

Comment: isn't page.php inside traderMVC/views ?

Comment: As your previous question,  `/traderMVC/page.php` is not the right path

Comment: well, page.php is in `traderMVC/views/` but your href points to `traderMVC/` only

Comment: and you still didn't accept (the only) answer of your last question, though you stated, that it resolved your problem. So, why should anybody...?

Comment: but: change `<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>` to `<?php echo VIEW_ROOT; ?>` and it should work. This still isn't something you couldn't get alone with printing out the paths, the constants,..

Comment: @Jeff I already had VIEW_ROOT, but I had the same issue..

Comment: I supoose in this case it should be '../views/page.php' (without the starting '/'). Or `BASE_URL.'/views/page.php'`. That's the logic you have to figure out yourself what suits your project best..

Comment: @Jeff The same.. Believe me I already tried all these things...

Comment: @Jeff  With VIEW_ROOT I am getting URLs of pages.php file:///C:/laragon/www/traderMVC/views/page.php?page=first-page

Comment: @user2486 In headeris just HTML <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>My System</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">

Comment: if the beginning is `file://` then you are not executing the php script at all.

Comment: you need to be calling your scripts via your (local) web server. (wamp or anything comareable)

Answer (score 0):

According to your structure , you need to add `views/templates` , change here

```
   <li><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>views/templates/page.php?page=<?php echo $page['slug']; ?>"><?php echo $page['label']; ?></a></li>
```